# Why is my observable returning null?

Tags: angular

I have the following method :

```
  public login(username: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    console.log('Sending the login credentials to obtain a token');
    const credentials = { 'email' : username, 'password' : password };
    const url: string = environment.USER_REST_URL + '/login';
    return this.httpClient.post<any>(url, credentials);
  }
```

It is called by :

```
  login(): void {
    // this.keycloakClientService.login(this.username, this.password).subscribe(
    this.userRestService.login(this.username, this.password).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.authService.setJwtTokenToLocalStorage(data.token);
        this.router.navigate(['user']);
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
```

But the data is null. However there is a response returned by the server.

The `error` block is not actioned and the flow goes in the `data` block.

I'm under Angular `6.0.4`.

UPDATE:
The mistake was simpler and totally mine : the server response was empty as its content was only a token set in the response `Authorization` header.

Here is how to have the response headers included in the response object

```
const credentials = { 'email' : username, 'password' : password };
// Have the response headers included in the response object
const options = {
  observe: 'response' as 'body'
};
const url: string = environment.USER_REST_URL + '/login';
return this.httpClient.post<any>(url, credentials, options);
```

And how to retrieve the header content

```
this.userRestService.login(this.username, this.password).subscribe(
  response => {
    const token = response.headers.get('Authorization');
    this.authService.setJwtTokenToLocalStorage(token);
    this.router.navigate(['user']);
  },
  error => {
    console.log(error);
  }
);
```

Comment: So, if you `console.log(data)` inside the `subscribe`, what is printed?

Comment: so it may be a problem with your json. can you attach the JSON response? maybe token is there but in a different level of the tree

Comment: The debugger tells me the data object is null. I can't find how to log the request and response on `Spring Boot 2.0.4`.

Comment: Your code doesn't  have any issues . I belive issues with response . Could you write the error block as well in subscribe method for better debugging.

Comment: @SuryaPrakashTumma I did but this `error` block is not actioned.

Comment: If you check in the browsers developer tools, in the network tab, you should be able to see the response that the server is sending back. Can you check that, and let us know what the response looks like?

Comment: @user184994 There is no response data. Spot on ! I should check on the server side and see what's going on. I suppose I'm not sending any data back.

Comment: The server is sending a token back in the response header. Now I need to find out how to retrieve that response header from the observable.